# is "mail command in linux" fire-and-forget or wait-until-mail-sent?

Tags: linux, multithreading, email, postfix-mta

I'm trying to send mail from my application server using the following code

```
FILE *mailer = popen("/usr/bin/mail -s 'Some subject here' user@domain", "w");
fprintf(mailer, "Hello %s,\nThis note is to inform you that your job completed successfully.\n", username);
pclose(mailer);
```

Question is, would I need to fork a thread to do this?
if the 'mail' command is 'fire-and-forget' opposed to 'wait-till-sent',
I guess I don't need a separate thread for this.

I'm using postfix for MTA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not usually. `mail` will start a mail transfer agent, hand it the message, and let it run in the background. If you have the `sendwait` option set, it will wait for it to be sent. That applies both when using an MTA, like sendmail or postfix, and when using SMTP directly (under the influence of the `smtp` option).

So, you need to know if the `sendwait` option is set - if you're not setting it on the command line, then it could be set in `.mailrc`, or as an environment variable.

All this is described in marginally more detail in the man page, if you want to know more.

Comment: Thanks!  man page says: the complete gnu mailutils manual is not available in debian system due to licensing reasons.... http://www.gnu.org/software/mailutils/manual/index.html is too big doc, can you point me where to look at in the doc?

Comment: That's weird. Fedora has Heirloom mail rather than GNU, so it has the man page. The man page for the version of mail i have is [here](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx/mailx.1.html) - just look for 'sendwait'